# How to expand a type alias (speifically a typle type) in Rust declarative macros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to adapt a macro that takes a variable number of type arguments, to a macro that takes a (possibly aliased) tuple type as its last argument:

```rust
macro_rules! serialize_individually2 {
  ($ecs:expr, $ser:expr, $data:expr, ($( $type:ty),*)) => {
      $(
      SerializeComponents::<NoError, SimpleMarker<SerializeMe>>::serialize(
          &( $ecs.read_storage::<$type>(), ),
          &$data.0,
          &$data.1,
          &mut $ser,
      )
      .unwrap();
      )*
  };
}
```

This works on non-aliased tuple types:

```rust
serialize_individually2!(ecs, serializer, data, (AreaOfEffect, BlocksTile));
```

But not on an aliased type:

```rust
type TupleComps = (AreaOfEffect, BlocksTile);
serialize_individually2!(ecs, serializer, data, TupleComps);
```

Is it possible to pattern match and de-alias `TupleComps` in a Rust macro?

Original question for reference (more generic, not as well thought out): [How to store a list of types using a Rust macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75031713/how-to-store-a-list-of-types-using-a-rust-macro)

Comment: No. But if you will expand more about the use case, maybe we will be able to help you do that without expanding the alias.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. However, you can create a trait that does the operation for tuples:

```rust
trait TupleReadStorage {
    fn read_storage(ecs: &mut Ecs) -> Self;
}

macro_rules! impl_TupleReadStorage {
    ( $first_item_type:ident $(, $rest_item_types:ident)* ) => {
        impl< $first_item_type, $($rest_item_types,)* > TupleReadStorage for ( $first_item_type, $($rest_item_types,)* ) {
            fn read_storage(ecs: &mut Ecs) -> Self {
                (
                    ecs.read_storage::<$first_item_type>(),
                    $( ecs.read_storage::<$rest_item_types>(), )*
                )
            }
        }
        impl_TupleReadStorage!( $($rest_item_types),* );
    };
    () => {
        impl TupleReadStorage for () {
            fn read_storage(_ecs: &mut Ecs) -> Self { () }
        }
    };
}

impl_TupleReadStorage!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J);
```

Then, use it in the macro:

```rust
macro_rules! serialize_individually2 {
    ($ecs:expr, $ser:expr, $data:expr, $type:ty) => {
        $(
            SerializeComponents::<NoError, SimpleMarker<SerializeMe>>::serialize(
                &<$type as TupleReadStorage>::read_storage(&mut $ecs),
                &$data.0,
                &$data.1,
                &mut $ser,
            )
            .unwrap();
        )*
    };
}
```